# Tomahawk maven repository for myfaces 3.0

Tags: myfaces, tomahawk

I have some web apps that are currently running in TOMEE8. TOMEE8 only supports jsf2.x.  So, these web apps are developed under jsf 2.x (myfaces 2.1) with Tomahawk20.

I am now working on migrating those apps to TOMEE9, which uses jsf3.x (myfaces3.0.2).  I am able to find the maven repository for myfaces3.0.2

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/3.0.2

But I failed to find Tomahawk30 in the maven repository. Is Tomahawk not available for myfaces 3.0?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.

Answer (score 1):

Tomahawk is in maintenance mode since many years, so there is no 3.0 version and will never be.

Please check the homepage: https://myfaces.apache.org/

I suggest you to migrate to PrimeFaces.

Comment: hopefully I can replace all tomahawk2.0 tags with the vanilla jsf 3.0 tags, without having to use PrimeFaces.